# Failing to install perl UNIVERSAL::DOES module

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm using Perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi and I'm trying to install [`UNIVERSAL::DOES`](https://metacpan.org/pod/UNIVERSAL%3a%3aDOES) from cpan (with sudo) using `install UNIVERSAL::DOES` and I get the following log:

```
Reading '/home/aris/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 10 Jun 2014 02:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'UNIVERSAL::DOES'
Checksum for /home/aris/.cpan/sources/authors/id/G/GF/GFUJI/UNIVERSAL-DOES-0.004.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /home/aris/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring G/GF/GFUJI/UNIVERSAL-DOES-0.004.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for UNIVERSAL::DOES
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  GFUJI/UNIVERSAL-DOES-0.004.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for G/GF/GFUJI/UNIVERSAL-DOES-0.004.tar.gz
cp lib/UNIVERSAL/DOES.pm blib/lib/UNIVERSAL/DOES.pm
Manifying blib/man3/UNIVERSAL::DOES.3pm
  GFUJI/UNIVERSAL-DOES-0.004.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00_load.t ... 1/1 # Testing UNIVERSAL::DOES/0.004
t/00_load.t ... ok   
t/01_basic.t .. 1/45 
#   Failed test at t/01_basic.t line 96.

#   Failed test at t/01_basic.t line 97.
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 45.
t/01_basic.t .. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 2/45 subtests 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/01_basic.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 45 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  33-34
  Non-zero exit status: 2
Files=2, Tests=46,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.01 sys +  0.07 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.13 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/2 test programs. 2/46 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 2
  GFUJI/UNIVERSAL-DOES-0.004.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports GFUJI/UNIVERSAL-DOES-0.004.tar.gz
Failed during this command:
  GFUJI/UNIVERSAL-DOES-0.004.tar.gz            : make_test NO
```

Is this the proper way to install it? Do I miss something? When I do `sudo apt-get install perl` I get that all are up to date.

Comment: perl v5.18 should already have [`UNIVERSAL->DOES`](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html) as part of Core.  That cpan module is specifically for older versions of perl.

Comment: cpan install YALM says ``Warning: Cannot install YALM, don't know what it is.``

Comment: Its called `YAML`, not `YALM`

Comment: YAML istalled but the package fails with the same warnings (expect YAML)

Comment: I know it's bad but I "hacked" the module. I downloaded it and commented the two lines that fail in t/01_basic.t (lines 96, 97). Then the module installed.

Comment: I think the 'correct' way to do that is: `cpan -f -i Module::Foo`

Comment: @John C. YAML is used by `cpan` to store information about installed modules. It's not used by UNIVERSAL::DOES's installer. This isn't the problem.

Comment: @Aris F., That's dumb. You've now installed a module its own tests say is broken. Now, it could be that the tests are bad, but it doesn't sound like you ascertained that before forcing the install.

Comment: @ikegami I did that before @john-c comment. I did a force install later, getting the same test fails but finishing the installation. I don't know perl and if this module should be installed, but the script without ``use UNIVERSAL::DOES`` fails.

Comment: Force install is the same thing
!

Answer (score 2):

The cpan module you're trying to install [`UNIVERSAL::DOES`](https://metacpan.org/pod/UNIVERSAL%3a%3aDOES) is specifically for versions of perl prior to v5.10 when [`DOES`](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html) was added to Core: [`"UNIVERSAL::DOES()" in perl5100delta`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5100delta#UNIVERSAL%3a%3aDOES).

You can find the module and inspect it using:

```
perl -MUNIVERSAL -e 'print $INC{"UNIVERSAL.pm"}'
```

Outputs (on my system)

```
C:/strawberry/perl/lib/UNIVERSAL.pm
```

Comment: ``perl -MUNIVERSAL -e 'print $INC{UNIVERSAL.pm}'`` return nothing on my system (ubuntu 14.04). Also, the program I want to run returns the message ``Can't locate UNIVERSAL/DOES.pm in @INC (you may need to install the UNIVERSAL::DOES module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /opt/tred/tred line 164.``. In line 164 is the command ``use UNIVERSAL::DOES;``

Comment: My first code was missing the double quotes:  `perl -MUNIVERSAL -e 'print $INC{"UNIVERSAL.pm"}'`

Comment: There's no harm in installed U::D on 5.10+, though. It just doesn't do anything.